# Mock object is not injected

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, testing, junit, mockito

I try mock controler:

```
@RestController
public class SthControl {
    @Autowired
    private ObjRepo repo;    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dosth", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ModelMap handleSth(@RequestParam("key") String key) { 
    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    logger.info("Is Mock "+ new MockUtil().isMock(repo));//return FALSE- is real object
logger.info("Key " + repo.loadByKey(key);//return NULL- always call real Method
```

**Test Case:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SthControlTest {
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Autowired
protected WebApplicationContext wac;
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private ObjRepo repo;

@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private SthControl contr;

@Before
public void setup() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();

    BasicConfigurator.configure();
}

@Test
public void testRegister() throws Exception {

    final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    final String keyValue = "KeyVal";

    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    repo = Mockito.mock(ObjtRepo.class);
    Mockito.when(repo.loadByKey(keyValue)).thenReturn(new Obj(uuid, keyValue, TimeUtils.currentTimeSecond(), false));
```

**Problem still exist if replace @Mock Annotation with this lines**

```
repo = Mockito.mock(ObjRepo.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(contr, "repo", repo, ObjRepo.class);
logger.info("Obj " + repo.loadByKey(keyValue).getId());//return correct object
logger.info("Mock Is "+new MockUtil().isMock(ReflectionTestUtils.getField(contr,"repo")));//True
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here.

- You need to swap the lines `this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();` and `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`, otherwise the injection done by the Spring web application context setup will overwrite the injection done by Mockito.  Always do the Spring injection first.
- You need to remove the line `repo = Mockito.mock(ObjtRepo.class);` from `testRegister`, because this line replaces the value in `repo` with one that differs from the one you injected, so when you stub the new value, it won't affect the behaviour of `SthControl`.

Comment: You don't understand me @David Wallace. Manually created `Mock` like `@InjectMock` has this same effect. Controller always contain "real" object- like without mocking.

Comment: OK.  Can you use a debugger to check whether the value of `repo` inside the `SthControl` object is the same before and after the call to `this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();`?  It may be that the Spring web application context setup is replacing the value that Mockito has injected.

Comment: Yes, debugger show that `Mock` is replaced by spring. How fix it??

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't have option delete answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer, to take account of the Spring problem as well as the redundant mock creation.